# What is the normal behaviour of HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3 when in charge and battery unconnected?

Tags: hp-elitebook

I'm attempting to diagnose a **HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3** with i7 processor, that does not charge nor start.

The battery was drained and there is no orange diode when charging.
The charging port is USB-C. The reset procedure (by pressing the power button 15 seconds) did not solve the issue.

I read that this laptop cannot start without the battery, because quite power hungry at start.

I am **not sure whether the problem comes from the battery or the mainboard**.

Hence, **I would like to know which is the normal behaviour of this laptop when the power supply is plugged in and the battery is disconnected**, so that I can compare:

1. **Does the diode light up and how?**  (fixed or flashing light? color? ...)
2. **Is the laptop able to start without its battery?**
3. Same behaviour if the laptop is without its SSD?

On the one here, when the charger is plugged in, the diode is blinking 8 times white.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HP Laptop does NOT boot without battery](https://superuser.com/questions/1637486/hp-laptop-does-not-boot-without-battery)

Comment: You need a battery, even a second-hand one.

Comment: "The battery was drained..." implies that the charge on the battery was allowed to drop to zero. That can quickly *destroy* most rechargeable batteries, whether Li-ion or old lead-acid (Ni-Fe batteries used in locomotive applications being an exception). As others stated, time for a new battery, ~US$30 to $50 at Amazon, for example.